# If a website stores a name and email address for authentication purposes, is that covered by GDPR?

Tags: security

I am setting up a website as a volunteer for a scout charity. As part of the web functionality we will be storing email addresses and names in a database with password hashes and some other info such as creation date and site roles.

Is this something that would be covered by GDPR? I have tried to do some reading online but can't seem to find something definitive that covers this use case.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Norman it is personal data and hence processing it (which includes storing it) comes under GDPR ambit, You may want to mention it in your privacy notice stating the high level purpose it is used for and just to ease the users let the users know, the data is not being passed to other third parties.
IAPP is good authoritative and credible site for all such queries. You may want to read this series.
https://iapp.org/news/a/business-impacts-of-the-general-data-protection-regulation-part-three/